# Term::ReadKey within a loop halts the enclosing loop

Tags: perl

I have a while loop that works. I want to capture keystrokes within that loop but the ReadKey routine halts the enclosing loop. What am I doing wrong?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Term::ReadKey;

my $char;

while(1 < 5) {
    print time . "\n";

    while(1) {
        ReadMode('raw');
        $char = ReadKey(0);
        print "Got $char\n";
    }
    sleep(5);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly clear from your question and the code you posted what you're trying to accomplish.  On the one hand the question sounds as if you're trying to get a non-blocking read.  If that's the case, you might want something more like this for your inner loop:

```
while(1) {
    ReadMode('cbreak');
    my $char = ReadKey(-1);
    next unless defined($char);
    print "Got $char\n";
    last if $char eq "\t";
}
```

ReadKey(-1) sets up a non-blocking read, which means it doesn't wait for input; it just tells you what the input is, if any, and then moves on to the next iteration.  If there's no input it returns undef.  You'll notice I switched the ReadMode to 'cbreak', for testing purposes, so that I could easily hit CTRL-C when I was ready to terminate.  Hitting tab would also terminate in this example code.  Since the ReadMode() is set to -1, for non-blocking, we just keep looping.

Your code also had the issue of "`while( 1 < 5 )`".  What good do you think that's doing for you?  1 is always less than 5, so that loop will never terminate.  If you really want a neverending loop, just say `while(1)` so we know you know what you mean.  On the other hand, I considered the possibility that you really meant to say something like `while( $i++ < 5 )` so that you would get at least five iterations of the outer loop.

One final note.  Whatever "ReadMode" you set, you really should call "`ReadMode('restore')`" before exiting the program, or your terminal may remain 'goofy'.  For example, on mine, without putting a `ReadMode('restore');` at the end of the program, hitting enter wouldn't give me a new line in my terminal.  This module doesn't seem to clean up after itself on termination, so you have to do it explicitly.

You should also look over the documentation for [Term::ReadKey](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Term%3a%3aReadKey).  Most of what I've discussed here is right there for the reading if you but look.

Comment: That 1 < 5 is old code that I was testing with. It should be while(1) as you specified. What I am trying to accomplish is simple: In the main while loop (the one that had 1 < 5), I pull data from an external source and display it. Then in that main loop after display the data I switch the ReadMode so I can capture keys. After the while loop to capture keystrokes I sleep(5) and go again. However, the while loop for the ReadKey pauses the parent loop so the refresh is not happening.

Comment: The actual code can be found here: http://pastebin.gdanko.net/459 Line 24 is executed and the data is displayed. I don't think the sleep statement on line 32 is ever hit so there is the next iteration is never executed.

Comment: That's the problem with posting irrelevant code: We didn't know that you were taking input both inside and outside of the inner while() loop, and that makes a difference.  The very next line following the end of the inner while() loop needs to set ReadMode('restore').  The 'cbreak' or 'raw' modes are fouling up your other input source.